# Optimization of wind farm using Penalty function in Scipy

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

In the following code I want to optimize a wind farm using a penalty function.

Using the first function(`newsite`), I have defined the wind turbines numbers and layout. Then in the next function, after importing `x0`(`c=x0`=initial guess), for each range of 10 wind directions (`wd`) I took the `c` values for the mean wd of each range. For instance, for `wd:[0,10]` mean value is `5` and I took `c` values of `wd=5` and put it for all `wd` in the range`[0,10]` and for each wind speed(`ws`). I have to mention that `c` is the value that shows that wind turbines are off or on(`c=0` means `wt` is off). then I have defined `operating` according to the `c`, which means that if `operating` is 0,`c=0` and that wt is off.

Then I defined the penalty function to optimize power output. indeed wherever `TI_eff>0.14`, I need to implement a penalty function so this function must be subtracted from the original power output. For instance, if `sim_res.TI_eff[1][2][3] > 0.14`, so I need to apply penalty function so `curr_func[1][2][3]=sim_res.Power[1][2][3]-10000*(sim_res.TI_eff[1][2][3]-0.14)**2`.

The problem is that I run this code but it did not give me any results and I waited for long hours, I think it was stuck in a loop that could not reach converge. so I want to know what is the problem?

```
import time

from py_wake.examples.data.hornsrev1 import V80 
from py_wake.examples.data.hornsrev1 import Hornsrev1Site # We work with the Horns Rev 1 site, which comes already set up with PyWake.
from py_wake import BastankhahGaussian
from py_wake.turbulence_models import GCLTurbulence
from py_wake.deflection_models.jimenez import JimenezWakeDeflection
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from py_wake.wind_turbines.power_ct_functions import PowerCtFunctionList, PowerCtTabular
import numpy as np

def newSite(x,y):
    xNew=np.array([x[0]+560*i for i in range(4)])
    yNew=np.array([y[0]+560*i for i in range(4)])    
    x_newsite=np.array([xNew[0],xNew[0],xNew[0],xNew[1]])
    y_newsite=np.array([yNew[0],yNew[1],yNew[2],yNew[0]])

    return (x_newsite,y_newsite)



def wt_simulation(c):
    
    c = c.reshape(4,360,23)
    site = Hornsrev1Site()
    x, y = site.initial_position.T
    x_newsite,y_newsite=newSite(x,y)
    windTurbines = V80()
    
    
    for item in range(4):
        for j in range(10,370,10):
            for i in range(j-10,j):
                c[item][i]=c[item][j-5]
          
    windTurbines.powerCtFunction = PowerCtFunctionList(
    key='operating',
    powerCtFunction_lst=[PowerCtTabular(ws=[0, 100], power=[0, 0], power_unit='w', ct=[0, 0]), # 0=No power and ct
                         windTurbines.powerCtFunction], # 1=Normal operation
    default_value=1)

    operating = np.ones((4,360,23)) # shape=(#wt,wd,ws)
    operating[c <= 0.5]=0
    
    wf_model = BastankhahGaussian(site, windTurbines,deflectionModel=JimenezWakeDeflection(),turbulenceModel=GCLTurbulence())

    # run wind farm simulation
    sim_res = wf_model(
        x_newsite, y_newsite, # wind turbine positions
        h=None, # wind turbine heights (defaults to the heights defined in windTurbines)
        wd=None, # Wind direction (defaults to site.default_wd (0,1,...,360 if not overriden))
        ws=None, # Wind speed (defaults to site.default_ws (3,4,...,25m/s if not overriden))
        operating=operating
   )
    
    curr_func=np.ones((4,360,23))
    for i in range(4):
        for l in range(360):
            for k in range(23):
                  if sim_res.TI_eff[i][l][k]-0.14 > 0 :
                      curr_func[i][l][k]=sim_res.Power[i][l][k]-10000*(sim_res.TI_eff[i][l][k]-0.14)**2
                  else:
                      curr_func[i][l][k]=sim_res.Power[i][l][k]
    
    return -float(np.sum(curr_func))  # negative because of scipy minimize
         
t0 = time.perf_counter()

        
def solve():
    
    wt =4  # for V80  
    wd=360
    ws=23
    x0 = np.ones((wt,wd,ws)).reshape(-1)  # initial value for c
    b=(0,1)
    bounds=np.full((wt,wd,ws,2),b).reshape(-1, 2)

    
    res = minimize(wt_simulation, x0=x0, bounds=bounds)

    return res
    
res=solve()

print(f'success status: {res.success}')
print(f'aep: {-res.fun}')  # negative to get the true maximum aep
print(f'c values: {res.x}\n')
print(f'elapse: {round(time.perf_counter() - t0)}s')  

sim_res=wt_simulation(res.x)
```

Comment: Where is it stuck? Use a debugger or some print statements to find out.

Comment: honestly, I am not familiar with debugger, because of this, I could not find the problem. also maybe there is a problem in my code that causes divergency that I could not find it.

Comment: How about putting a "print" statement just before returning the value of the objective function? I.e., define:

of = -float(np.sum(curr_func)) 
print(of)
return of

Comment: @Infinity77 how can i use both print and return in the same function?

Comment: I don't see why not - why would there be any reason not to be able to use them both? My 3 lines of code above are of course one after the other, not inline as they appear in the comment.

By the way, your triple loop as it is now is phenomenally inefficient. I am not terribly familiar with PyWake but I would assume the library would be able to return 2D/3D arrays of power data given wind directions/speed/etc...

Comment: @Infinity77 since as far as i knew in a function we just use one of them to get output, but maybe i am making a mistake. I did this but i could not see any result. the fact is that i deleted the last triple loop(from cuu_func) and used print, to see what are the results, in fact in each iteration it gives the same result. indeed the initial guess always remain the same and i will not change and i do not why?

Comment: @mkrieger1, the problem is that after each iteration, the code will input the same initial guess. indeed initial guess remains the same in each iteration and will not change(so always xo=c, for each iteration) and the optimization will not work properly and I do not why?  I do not know how can I solve this problem?

Comment: You can use print() as many times as you want and in any place you want. I'd suggest you familiarize yourself a bit more with the basics of Python before attempting to write/run complex things. One thing I noticed is that I do not understand what your objective function is supposed to do. What are your optimization parameters? You have 4 turbines, that's it, you can't optimize on wind speed or direction.

Comment: no no, actually I could not understand your question because of this I told you how can I print it? yes, I did it and put some print to see the results and I understand that the initial guess which is x0 and related to c is not updated after each iteration in the optimization procedure. in this code, I want to maximize power output which is -float(np. sum(curr_func)) by changing c. indeed by switching off/on turbines I want to get the best compromise of power.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things in your approach that are either wrong or incomprehensible to me. Just for fun I have tried your code. A few observations:

1. Your set of parameters (optimization variables) has a shape of (4, 360, 23), i.e. you are looking at 33,120 parameters. There is no nonlinear optimization algorithm that is going to give you any meaningful answer to a problem that big. Ever. But then again, you shouldn't be looking at SciPy optimize if your optimization variables should only assume 0/1 values.
2. Calling SciPy minimize like this:

   `res = minimize(wt_simulation, x0=x0, bounds=bounds)`

   Is going to select a nonlinear optimizer between BFGS, L-BFGS-B or SLSQP  (according to the documentation at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html)

   Those algorithms are gradient-based, and since you're not providing a gradient of your objective function SciPy is going to calculate them numerically. Good luck with that when you have 33,000 parameters. Never going to finish.
3. At the beginning of your objective function you are doing this:

   for item in range(4):
   for j in range(10,370,10):
   for i in range(j-10,j):
   c[item][i]=c[item][j-5]

   I don't understand why you're doing it but you are overriding the input values of c coming from the optimizer.
4. Your objective function takes 20-25 seconds to evaluate on my powerful workstation. Even if you had only 10-15 optimization parameters, it would take you several days to get any answer out of an optimizer. You have 33,000+ variables. No way.

I don't know why you are doing this and why you're doing it the way you're doing it. You should rethink your approach.

Comment: thanks a lot. Actually,indeed my professor proposed to do it on scipy. is it possible to do this using pyswarm? regarding the point 3, yes you are right indeed I can use it in initial guess(x0) so by doing this I can define x0=4*36*23 instead of 360. I used this line since I want to say that for a range of 10 wind directions (wd) we have the same values of C. so do you think now the inputs numbers are acceptable?